# node.js sequelize no primary keys when migrating

Tags: database, sequelize.js, migrate

This is my `create_user_table` migration in my node.js project.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("comments", {
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("comments")
  }
};
```

After running sequelize db:migrate this is the result:

```
sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.15.2, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.8.5]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20190507193540-create_comment_table: migrating =======
== 20190507193540-create_comment_table: migrated (0.021s)

== 20190507195058-create_user_table: migrating =======
== 20190507195058-create_user_table: migrated (0.011s)
```

When I run `describe users;` in mysql CLI, the table does not include an ID?

```
   +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | username | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | lastName | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And to completely make sure, I've also tried.

```
mysql> show index from users where id = 'PRIMARY';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must manually declare an `id` field in your model and migration file, e.g.:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("comments", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
      }
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("comments")
  }
};
```

Comment: Kind of documented at: https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-createTable on the example. Feels like bad API.